# Need help solving permission error on navision 2013 webservices

Tags: web-services, navision

I think this question border on both programmers and server admin knowledge so let's hope I choose the correct forum.

I need to make an application communicate with Microsoft dynamics 2013 using it's web-services.

At the moment I can successfully query the systemservice for the list of companies in the installation. (http://:7047/NAV2013/WS/systemservice)

However when I try to access the list ofcompany specific published services (http://:7047/nav2013/WS//services) I get an error about permissions I apparently do not have. Googling the error yielded very little result.

The account I use for access has the super permission set and the webservices have been set to use ntlm authentication not kerberos.

the error

```
<s:Envelope><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode>a:Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Types.NavPermissionException</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">You do not have the following permissions on TableData Page Data Personalization: Read</faultstring><detail><string>You do not have the following permissions on TableData Page Data Personalization: Read</string></detail></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Hope somebody is familiar with the error, because I do not get it.